# Is there a 'VIM like Desert Theme' for NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

Is there a VIM like Desert Theme for NetBeans - A NetBeans Desert Color Scheme
I think VIM Desert Theme is simply Perfect
I couldnt find any Desert Scheme for NetBeans

Comment: I really hope so too, it's far more pleasant than anything that is included by default.

Answer (score 7):

This author claims he created a NetBeans color scheme based off of the Desert theme from VIM.

http://marcfearby.com/computing/desert-colour-scheme-for-netbeans

NetBeans IDE has a simple import/export for syntax highlighting themes via Tools -> Editor, see the button in lower left corner.